# Could not resolve host: https Bitbucket Git bash issue

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

Hi i am trying to update files from my local to bit bucket through Git Bash. I get an error like

```
$ git fetch && git checkout master
fatal: unable to access 'https://https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ex.git/': Could not resolve host: https
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `https://` twice in the remote URL. Check the remote with `git remote -v`.

## Change it using `set-url`

Change the remote directly using `set-url`:

`git remote set-url origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ex.git`

## Change it using `rm` and `add`

Remove the remote using `git remote rm origin`

Add the correct remote:
`git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ex.git`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** :

remove redundant **https** and unset http/https proxy (in your case https)

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```